# How to write a custom conv2d layer for two images in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

My research requires me to make a custom convolutional layer. Suppose I have an input with two images [W, H, 2, C] and a kernel [w, w, 2, c]. My goal is to decouple the kernel movements in each image.

That is, suppose the kernels are in the upper-left corner. In the first step, I want the kernel to move one step left in image 1 but stay at the same position in image 2. Then to repeat the same until the kernel is not finished the first row in image 1. Then the kernel in image 1 goes back to the initial position while the kernel in image 2 moves one step to the right. Repeat the same algorithm until the kernel in image 2 is not finished the first row. Then move both kernels one step down and repeat the whole process. Do the same until the kernels are not swept the whole image.

Is it any way to implement such an algorithm in TensorFlow?